# simulate isotropic linear diffusion smoothing

Tags: opencv, filtering, smoothing

I want to apply the de-noising filter I named in the title which is based on the following equations:

[image]

where `d = 1` is a scalar constant diffusivity parameter, `I(x, y)` is the initial noisy image, and `u(x, y, t)` is the image obtained after a diffusion time `t` lets say `5, 10 and 30`. However, I am quite confused about which function to use and how, in order to achieve this in OpenCV. I have the feeling that it is quite simple but for some reason I am confused. Does anyone have an idea?

Here is a sample image:

[image]

I want then to compare it with a gaussian filtering approach which according the following:

[image]

where `G√2t (x, y)` is the Gaussian kernel. This proves that performing isotropic linear diffusion for a time `t` with `d = 1` is exactly equivalent to performing Gaussian smoothing with a `σ = √(2t)`

I have a function that applies the gaussian filtering:

```
void gaussian_2D_convolution(const cv::Mat& src, cv::Mat& dst, const float sigma, const int ksize_x = 0, const int ksize_y = 0)
{
    int ksize_x_ = ksize_x, ksize_y_ = ksize_y;

    // Compute an appropriate kernel size according to the specified sigma
    if (sigma > ksize_x || sigma > ksize_y || ksize_x == 0 || ksize_y == 0)
    {
        ksize_x_ = (int)ceil(2.0f*(1.0f + (sigma - 0.8f) / (0.3f)));
        ksize_y_ = ksize_x_;
    }

    // The kernel size must be and odd number
    if ((ksize_x_ % 2) == 0)
    {
        ksize_x_ += 1;
    }

    if ((ksize_y_ % 2) == 0)
    {
        ksize_y_ += 1;
    }

    // Perform the Gaussian Smoothing
    GaussianBlur(src, dst, Size(ksize_x_, ksize_y_), sigma, sigma, BORDER_DEFAULT);

    // show result
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << std::setprecision(1) << std::fixed << sigma;
    String title = "sigma: " + out.str();
    imshow(title, dst);
    imwrite("gaussian/" + title + ".png", dst);

    waitKey(260);
}
```

but I have difficulties implementing the first case.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as expected. This is based on:

- [Octave Perona & Malik smooth](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/imsmooth.html)
- the comment on your question on [answer.opencv](http://answers.opencv.org/question/70552/isotropic-linear-diffusion-smoothing/)

Code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

void ilds(const Mat1b& src, Mat1b& dst, int iter = 10, double diffusivity = 1.0, double lambda = 0.1)
{
    Mat1f img;
    src.convertTo(img, CV_32F);
    lambda = fmax(0.001, std::fmin(lambda, 0.25)); // something in [0, 0.25] by default should be 0.25
    while (iter--)
    {
        Mat1f lap;
        Laplacian(img, lap, CV_32F);
        img += lambda * diffusivity * lap;
    }

    img.convertTo(dst, CV_8U);
}

int main() {

    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat1b res_ilds;
    ilds(img, res_ilds);

    imshow("ILDS", res_ilds);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Hi @Miki thank you for your answer and your time. I will try it as soon as I will return back to my workstation. However one question, since your approach is based on the Perona-Malik method it is not simulating an isometric linear smoothing but an anisotropic nonlinear instead, am l right?

Comment: @theodore It's _isotropic_! P&M: `I += lambda * (g(dN).*dN + g(dS).*dS + g(dE).*dE + g(dW).*dW)`, where `dN` is the spatial derivative of the image in the North direction, and so forth. The function g determines the behaviour of the diffusion. If `g(x) = 1` (like in this case) this is standard isotropic diffusion.

Comment: ok I see running your code works as you are saying. However, I want to verify some things though. As I understand the `g` function corresponds to the diffusivity parameter `d` right ? If yes then your code more correctly can be transformed to `img += lambda *d* lap;` where `d` is 1. Moreover, the `iter` variable represents the diffusion time `t` parameter, right? However, if I use a value of 5 for `iter` that should correspond to a `σ = √(2t) = 3.2` for the gaussian smoothing and both should give me the same result but they do not. Also in my the initial formula there is not any `lambda`

Comment: variable mentioned so how is this added to the calculation. Lastly, you are using the laplacian filter in order to obtain the derivatives, could I use the sobel or scharr filter for getting the derivatives, would that change anything or it does not matter which method I will use for obtaining it.

Comment: @theodore `img += lambda *d* lap` correct. `iter` correct. _if I use..._ don't know actually. `lambda` is in th formulation of P&M, you can fix it to the default of 0.25. You need the Laplacian, you can compute it with Sobel but I don't see a good reason why. Let me know

Comment: ok, so everything is understandable now except the part with the iterations and the corresponding sigma to the gaussian smoothing that doesn't work as intended.

Comment: @theodore feel free to edit the code and change name variables, add the diffusivity, etc. Regarding the comparison with gaussian blur actually I don't know. Probably the `lambda` is the key (try putting it to the default value of 0.25). Also check that gaussian kernel size is "big enough".

Comment: yup I will :-). I am using now the default value for `lambda = 0.25`. However, it does not change anything. Also the gaussian kernel size for a `σ = 3.2` is 19.

Comment: @theodore well, good luck. Please let me know that now I'm quite curious about this :D

Comment: yup, thank you anyway for your time and your help :-). When I find out what is the issue with the diffusion time I will edit your answer and accept it as correct ;-).

Comment: @theodore thanks. feel free to post your own answer :D